# for loop to split string into words doesn't include the last word

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops, for-loop

I'm supposed to write this code so it returns a list from a string, and I would like to do that without recurring to list() or split() functions , but try to write my own function, a mimic of split(), but that separates by space only.

Here's the code:

```
def mysplit(strng):
    res = []
    word = ""
    for i in range(len(strng)):
        if strng[i] != " ":
            word += strng[i]
        else:
            res.append(word)
            word = ""
        
    if len(res) > 0:
        return res
    else:
        return []
#These below are tests.
print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```

This is the expected output:

```
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
[]
['abc']
[]
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,', 'that', 'is', 'the']
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,that', 'is', 'the']
['', '', '']
['', 'abc']
[]
```

Comment: You should explain what the actual output is versus expected output.

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks, will do.

Comment: `for i in range(len(strng))` certainly iterates through the whole range of string.

Comment: append a white-space to your string, `strng2 = strng + ' '`, as a 1st line of the function's body and use the latter later in your code... then no additional final check will be required

Comment: @cards Your suggestion is unclear (to me). Can you provide this idea as an answer?

Comment: @DarkKnight done. The "final check" is meant wrt Hasan Patel's answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need *range()* for this because you can iterate over the source string without any concern for its length. Something like this:

```
def mysplit(s):
    words = ['']
    for c in s:
        if c == ' ':
            if words[-1]:
                words.append('')
        else:
            words[-1] += c
    return words if words[-1] else words[:-1]

print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```

**Output:**

```
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
[]
['abc']
[]
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is made of two phases: left/right *strip* and a *split*.

In the following the code is meant to be the most similar to the original one.

---

From the comment: use an extended string with an extra white space appended at the end. This will fix **only** the *last word* problem.

```
def mysplit(strng):
    strng_ = strng + " " # <- extended string
    res = []
    word = ""
    for i in range(len(strng_)):
        if strng_[i] != " ":
            word += strng_[i]
        else:
            res.append(word)
            word = ""
        
    return res


tests = "To be or not to be, that is the question", "  To be or not to be, that is the question   ", " "

for test in tests:
    print(mysplit(test))
```

Here a full solution of the problem. It needs only an extra check.

```
def mysplit(strng):
    strng_ = strng + " " # <- extended string
    res = []
    word = ""
    for i in range(len(strng_)):
        if strng_[i] != " ":
            word += strng_[i]
        else:
            # check empty word
            if word:
                res.append(word)
            word = ""
        
    return res
```

---

Here another complete solution which is based on a DIY left/right strip

```
def mysplit(text):
    # left-strip
    c = 0
    for char in text:
        if char == " ":
            c += 1
        else:
            break

    # right-strip
    # reversed string
    text_ = text[c:][::-1]
    c = 0
    for char in text_:
        if char == " ":
            c += 1
        else:
            break

    # striped string
    text_ = text_[c:][::-1]
    
    # check empty string
    if not text_:
        return []
    
    # DIY-split
    text_ += " " # <- extended string
    res = []
    word = ""
    for i in range(len(text_)):
        if text_[i] != " ":
            word += text_[i]
        else:
            res.append(word)
            word = ""
        
    return res
```

Remark: `str.isspace` could be used instead of `str == " "`

Comment: is the result wrong?